# Why I am having unwanted space between tabbar and body. I am using SilverApp bar.(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[I am having this unwanted space anyone has any idea how to solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPMYC.png)

Comment: You should share code to get the exact response

Comment: Share your code in your question for others to understand where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the tab bar or every widget that has unexpected space with a PreferredSize widget of height 0:

```
SliverAppBar(
      bottom: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
      child: TabBar(
      tabs: _tabs
           .map((String name) => Tab(text: name))
           .toList()),
),)
```